# Array size error

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is my code:

The marked line is giving the error.

```
class Student{
public:
    //Student(string x, int y, string z[]);
    void getinfo();
    void printinfo();

private:
    string name;
    int numClasses;
    string arr[numClasses]; // the error is here it's not allowing me to put numClasses as the size   of 
                            // the class
};
```

Comment: Could you please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and state what your intentions are with this piece of code.

Comment: I'm having an error that im not being allowed to put a variable as my array size

Comment: int numClasses;
string arr[numClasses];

Answer (score 2):

The size of the array must be a constant integral expression

You can do something like this:

```
class Student
{
public:
    void getinfo();
    void printinfo();

private:
    string name;
    static const int numClasses = 20;
    string arr[numClasses];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, the array will be allocated at compile time, and so when the size is not a constant, the compiler cannot accurately determine its value and throws error.

if you want to use array with dynamic size, use vector.

Here, 
1) Change size to const
2) or, use vector  ->  `vector<string>arr;`

Answer (score 0):

Array should be constant here is some explanation that can help that I found in cpp website

> The elements field within brackets [] which represents the number of
>   elements the array is going to hold, must be a constant value, since
>   arrays are blocks of non-dynamic memory whose size must be determined
>   before execution. In order to create arrays with a variable length
>   dynamic memory is needed

since you have got your answer already I am just going to include great information about arrays that other might benefit from.

in c++ correct way to declare an array of 10 integers for example can be done this way

```
int array[10];
```

if you know a head of time what values you want in the array you can just do it this way

```
 int numbers [] = {13, 30, 50, 2, 5, 6, 70, 8, 9, 10};
```

"Pointer arithmetic" & regular arithmetic 
Pointer arithmetic is a way of expressing evaluations it uses 2 stacks one for characters and one for numbers for example pointer arithmetic uses *(a+1)" where as regular arithmetic uses "a[i]"
both are the same 
one of my professors talked a lot about arrays

```
  and say array[i] = *(a+i)
  what does that mean?
  it basically means 
  if a[i] = a[0]
  then in pointer arithmetic it is :
  *(a+0);
  and if a[i] = a[1]
  then in pointer arithmetic it is :
  *(a+1); and so on
```

basically I shared about 2 weeks of my data structure course :P
    hope I was able to help

Comment: actually, this isn't true, unless u r using a very old compiler

Comment: No one would actually do the *(a+i) cuz at the end its from "C" but that' how we have been taught about arrays and pointer arithmetic.  http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/68-pointers-arrays-and-pointer-arithmetic/